# see/// ,sm. upi eo;; gohitr yjod piy/

Tags: cipher, english

> see/// ,sm. upi eo;; gohitr yjod piy/

Did you solve it? If so, post your answer below. Go solve it! It is really easy. It is a common secret language. (Not really secret though.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ur kiija kujw \ jwtvi\es agudr xuogwe, [sxisw,de](https://dcode.fr/) g\a \ o\fw die \yrin\rux\kkt swxetorubf ur,

Comment: Added the [tag:english] tag to mitigate the layout issues some may be experiencing.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: aww... man, you will figure this out.

> As @codewarrior0 says, dcode.fr can solve it as Keyboard Shifted ciphertext with Automatic settings.

Detailed cipher settings:

> Plaintext expected language: English;  Keyboard Layout: QWERTY (US); Shift: Right; Number of keys/steps for shift: 1 key